# Base class method being called instead of derived, even when passed by reference

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have 3 classes: `A`, `B`, and `AnotherClass`. Where `B` is derived from `A`:

```
class A {
public:
    A(){}
    virtual void method() {//default action}
};
```

Then I have a derived class, B:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B(){}
    void method() {//redefine action}
};
```

And `AnotherClass`:

```
class AnotherClass {
public:
    AnotherClass(A& a);
    A a;
    anotherMethod(){ a.method()}
};
AnotherClass :: AnotherClass(A& a) : a(a) //initialization
```

So, if I construct an object of `AnotherClass` with an object of `B`:

```
B b();
AnotherClass myObj(b);
```

Keep in mind, since `B` inherits from `A`, and `AnotherClass` accepts an object of `A`, I am able to successfully pass in a `B` object as the argument.

And I call:

```
myObj.anotherMethod();
```

I expect this to execute `anotherMethod()`, and when it does, I expect it to call the REDEFINED `method()` that belongs to `B`, but instead it calls the default `method()` defined in `A`

I was thinking my problem is because I specify the argument of `AnotherClass` as an object of `class A`. However, I do not want to change this argument to an object of `class B` because I also have classes `C`, `D`, and `E`, that also inherit directly from `A`. So I want to use the base class as the argument type so I am not limited to only being able to pass in a `b` object. But, I read some older posts on this site and most proposed solutions was to pass the derived object (`b`) by reference, which I am doing.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: *I was thinking my problem is because I specify the argument of AnotherClass as an object of class A* You are correct.  You need to store a reference or pointer to `A` in the class.

Comment: I've edited it, but not this: `B b();` - is your code even compiling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to the constructor is fine.  It is an object of type `B` passed by reference to the `A` subobject.  The problem is that you copy the `A` subobject *only* (and not the derived object) into the member variable `a`.  Then when you call `a.method()` there is only a base object there, so the base function is called.

The solution is to make the member variable be a pointer or a reference (and not a copy) of the argument.  (Note that in either case, you will then need to make sure that the object you pass in, will live at least as long as the `AnotherClass` object.

Answer (score 2):

It will only work if it is a pointer `A* a`
Look up on polymorphism.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

if you wont to know more , read the article

Comment: `A *a(b);` is a compilation error.  `A &a(b);` will also work.

Comment: Wrong and completely unrelated to the problem (which is slicing when he stores the reference to an instance of A in the AnotherClass constructor).

Comment: A *a=new A(b);  this is nicer :) sorry

Comment: a) It will *not* work "only" for pointers. b) what you have marked as working will not work. -1.

Comment: `new A(b)` will copy-construct an `A` object from the base of the `b` object.  `a->method()` will call the base class function, not the derived class function.

Answer (score 2):

You are slicing in your constructor to `AnotherClass`.  Note you have a value of type `A` as a member.  So the compiler is doing the right thing.  You don't have a `B` at the point you call `a.method()`.