# Pass a pointer or reference to derived class such that base class method is called

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I have a derived class and a base class that both override the same virtual function. How can I pass some other function a pointer or reference to an instance of the derived class, but still call the base class's version of the virtual function?

---

I appear to have precisely the opposite problem from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732840/base-class-method-being-called-instead-of-derived-even-when-passed-by-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1). I effectively want to slice my derived object so that it looks like a base object (assuming I can do so safely), but can't figure out how to do it.

I have a large set of data that would be expensive to copy, so I instead pass around a lightweight `view` object that allows iteration. I have an interface that various datasets inherit to advertise that they can provide a `view`:

```
class data_interface
{
    virtual view get_view() = 0;
};
```

There's a base class that owns one of these datasets, and can provide a view to it on request:

```
class base_owns_data : public data_interface
{
public:
    view get_view() override
    {
        return view(d);
    }

private:
    data d;
};
```

That class works fine in isolation. My application does things like pass it by reference to free functions, in order to get a more complex view into the data:

```
view some_process(base_owns_data &b)
{
    auto working_view = b.get_view();
    // Do a bunch of things to filter the view
    return working_view;
}
```

(Please note that the above is stripped down for the MCVE - here, it would make more sense to directly take a `view` parameter, but in context I'm combining several datasets and one of them needs to own the storage rather than just having view to it)

The problem appears when I try to extend the base dataset with another that needs to do some extra processing. Here's a derived class:

```
class derived_owns_data : public base_owns_data
{
public:
    base_owns_data& as_base()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    view get_view() override
    {
        return some_process(this->as_base());   
    }
};
```

What I wanted to happen is that, since `some_process` is being passed a reference to `base_owns_data`, that `base_owns_data::get_view()` would be called in `some_process`.

What actually happens is that `some_process` still calls `derived_owns_data::get_view()`. This results in an infinite loop as those two functions call each other back and forth.

I'm not sure what to do - I can't remove `virtual` from the interface, or the interface becomes useless. I don't want to copy the data, either. But I can't figure out how to force `base_owns_data::get_view()` to be called on a reference of type `derived_owns_data`.

I tried passing a pointer instead of a reference, but that still seems to cause an infinite loop.

How can I safely make the derived class appear to be a base class in `some_process`?

---

Full MCVE (or on [ideone](https://ideone.com/lPtJ8f)):

```
struct data
{
    char c[100];
};

class view
{
public:
    view(data d) :
        first(&d.c[0]),
        last(&d.c[100])
    {

    }
private:
    char * first;
    char * last;
};

class data_interface
{
    virtual view get_view() = 0;
};

class base_owns_data : public data_interface
{
public:
    view get_view() override
    {
        return view(d);
    }

private:
    data d;
};

view some_process(base_owns_data &b)
{
    return b.get_view();
}

class derived_owns_data : public base_owns_data
{
public:
    base_owns_data& as_base()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    view get_view() override
    {
        return some_process(this->as_base());   
    }
};


int main() {
    derived_owns_data d;
    d.get_view();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't slice an existing object. That would imply changing it's type. Object slicing occurs when copying from a derived type to a base type.

Comment: Perhaps this could be solved with the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: Regarding polymorphism, the object's actual type is distinct from the type used to refer to it. The goal of using `virtual` functions is that it the derived type behaves correctly even if it's referred to by a pointer or reference to one of it's base types. Casting the reference or pointer to a base type doesn't alter which `virtual` function will get called as that would entirely defeat the purpose of polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly call overriden function from base class:

```
view some_process(base_owns_data &b)
{
    auto working_view = b.base_owns_data::get_view();
    // Do a bunch of things to filter the view
    return working_view;
}
```

Comment: Never occurred to me to qualify a call on a reference with its own (apparent) type - thanks!